# The powers of non-empty subset of a group that generate a subgroup 

Tags: finite-groups, gr.group-theory, nt.number-theory

If G is a group and A and B to non-empty subsets of G, then by AB we mean the set consist of all product ab where a is in A and b is in B.(Standard definition) Similarly we can define X^m where X is a non-empty subset and m is a positive integer. So X^m for positive integer m, means the set of all products of length m taken from X.

**If G is a group of size n, and X is a non-empty subset of G then prove that X^n is a subgroup of G.**

this is quite easy to prove for abelian groups, so I mostly like to see a short nice proof for the  general case.

Comment: Also posted to Math StackExchange, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/212076/in-a-group-of-size-n-any-n-th-power-of-a-subset-is-a-subgroup/212085#212085 --- with no cross-reference on either site. Shame. 

Answer (score 10):

Consider the sets $X, X^2, \dots$. We claim that $|X^i|\leq |X^{i+1}|$, and, moreover, if $|X^i|=|X^{i+1}|$ then $|X^{i+1}|=|X^{i+2}|$. Actually, under the mapping $X^i\times X\to X^{i+1}$, $(b,x)\mapsto bx$, the preimage of any element of $X^{i+1}$ has the cardinality at most $|X|$ since all $x$-coordinates in this preimage should be distinct. Thus, $|X^i|\cdot |X|\leq |X^{i+1}|\cdot |X|$; hence $|X^i|\leq |X^{i+1}|$, and $|X^{i+1}|=|X^i|$ iff this cardinality is always $|X|$, that is -- iff $bxy^{-1}\in X^i$ for all $b\in X^i$ and $x,y\in X$. This obviously implies $cxy^{-1}\in X^{i+1}$ for all $c\in X^{i+1}$ and $x,y\in X$, and, conversely, this means that $|X^{i+1}|=|X^{i+2}|$.

Now, if $|X^n|=n$ then $X^n=G$, and the claim is trivial. Otherwise, $|X^i|=|X^{i+1}|$ for some $i\leq n-1$, and hence $|X^i|=|X^{i+1}|=\dots=|X^n|=\dots=|X^{2n}|$. Since $X^n\subseteq X^{2n}$, the latter implies that $X^n$ is a subgroup.

**NB.** Some background is left aside this proof. Let $H=\langle X^n\rangle$, $K=\langle X\rangle$. Since $X^{-1}\subseteq X^{n-1}$, we have $H\triangleleft K$; moreover, $XX^{-1}\subset H$, so $X$ lies in one coset modulo $H$. Hence $K/H$ is cyclic, and $X^i$ also lies in one coset modulo $H$.

Now the arguments above show that $|X^i|=|X^{i+1}|$ iff $X^i$ **is** a coset modulo $H$. Hence, if $k$ is the least multiple of $|K/H|$ which is not less than $|H|$, then even $X^k=H$.

Comment: You have to be more careful with the last inclusion.  You have to assert (something like) that X^n contains the identity to make sure
the inclusion follows.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.10.14

Comment: Moreover, the whole argument breaks down if 1 is not in X. 

Comment: @Gerhard: Well, if $|G|=n$, then surely $1=x^n\in X^n$ since $X$ is nonempty. @Misha: which part breaks down?

Comment: @Misha: Notice that I do not say $X^I$ lies in $X^{i+1}$; I speak only about cardinalities...

Comment: Ilya, the problem appears in "Otherwise, $|X_i|=|X_{i+1}|$ for some $i\le n−1$." The trouble is that the cardinality function $c(i)=|X_i|$ has no monotonicity properties unless $1\in X$, so "otherwise" has no justification. 

Comment: @Misha: From the same argument as in the first paragraph, we see that $|X^i|\leq |X^{i+1}|$ in any case.

Comment: @Ilya: very nice proof. I like it a lot. I do not think that anything is missing.

Comment: Ilya, it is a matter of clarity and what I like to call "defensive proving" (akin to "defensive programming").  Even though you make use of the size of the algebraic structure G in the previous sentences, you need that and that G is a group in order to have the proof go through.
Saying that just before the inclusion makes the proof portable, so you know what to reuse when the customer changes the premises.
Your proof works, but could be made more portable and more clear.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.10.15

Comment: @Ilya Bogdanov Respect! How could you can work out this question in such limited time? I got the same solution with yours but it took me two days and more.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer  $\mathbf{if}$ $1\in X$:

Denote by $H$ the subgroup of $G$ being generated by $X$.

What you want is to show that $H=X^n$, which amounts to see that any element of $H$ can be written as a product of at most $n$ elements of $X$.

This follows from the fact that the size of $H$ is at most $n$:

We write an element $h$ of $H$ as a product of $m$ elements of $X$: $h=x_mx_{m-1}\dots x_1$ then we look at the elements $h_i=x_{i}\dots x_{1}$ obtained by the products of $i$ elements only. If $m>n$, there are two $h_i$'s which are equal, say $h_a=h_b$ with $a>b$. We replace $h_a$ with $h_b$ and can write $h$ with less elements.

$\mathbf{Edit}:$ If $1\notin X$, then $X^n$ is maybe not the group generated by $X$ (take for example the case where $X$ is a single element), but is in fact a subgroup, as Ilya showed.

Comment: @Jérémy: "Since the order of $H$ is $\le n$, this is trivial". Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I edited my answer. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: Just a minor detail: if $X$ consists of a single non-identity element, the group $X^n$ is actually just the identity, and not the subgroup generated by $X$!

Comment: You want $1\in X$ for this to work. 

Comment: As Benjamin implicitly says, you have only proved that $H = \cup_{j=1}^{n}X^{j}$ by this argument.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Sorry. Now it is then just a partial answer. The case where $1$ does not belong to $X$ is then probably more interesting. 

Comment: @Geoff Robinson: I thought that in the text $n$ was the order of the group, but otherwise I agree with you!

Comment: In the question, $n$ is indeed the order of the group. As you said, otherwise $X^n$ could be not a group. Does someone has an answer in the case where $X$ contains more than $1$ element and that it does not contain the identity?

Comment: @MP: I forgot that $n$ was the order of the group- my mistake!

Answer (score 1):

The following is a rewrite of the proof of Ilya in a different language.  If you like it, upvote his answer.

Let $G$ be a finite group and $P(G)$ be the power set of $G$ which is a monoid.  The idempotents of $P(G)$ are precisely the subgroups $H$ of $G$ and the group of units of the submonoid $HP(G)H$ is $N_G(H)/H$ (this is classical finite semigroups theory; google power group).  This is the largest subsemigroup of $P(G)$ which is a group with identity $H$.

Let $|G|=n$ and $X\subseteq G$.  By general finite semigroup theory, $X^k=X^{k+m}$ for some $k,m$ which we take to be minimal.  Then $\{X^k,\ldots, X^{k+m-1}\}$ is a cyclic group with identity $X^r$ where $r$ is the unique power in that range divisible by $m$. Also $XX^j=XX^rX^j$ for $k\leq j\leq k+m-1$. Let $H=X^r$.

By the above discussion, we have that $k$ is the least power such that $X^k\in N_G(H)/H$. Observe first that $|X^{i+1}|\geq |X^i|$ because if $x\in X$, then $|X^i|=|X^ix|\leq |X^iX|=|X^{i+1}|$.

**Claim**. TFAE.

(1) $|X^i|=|X^{i+1}|$

(2) $|X^i|=|X^{i+j}|$ for $j\geq 0$

(3) $X^i\in N_G(H)/H$

(4) $|X^i|=|H|$.

Pf.  Suppose first (3) holds. Then $|X^i|=|H|$ so (3)  implies (4).

Suppose (4) holds.  Then since $|H|=|X^i|\leq |X^{i+1}|\leq |X^{i+r}|=|H|$ (as $X^{i+r}\in N_G(H)/H$), it follows that $|X^i|=|X^{i+1}|$. Thus (1) holds

Suppose (1) holds and fix $x\in X$. Then $X^{i+1}\supseteq xX^i$ and $|X^{i+1}| = |X^i|=|xX^i|$.  Thus $X^{i+1}=xX^i$.  Assume inductively that $X^{i+j}=x^jX^i$.  Then $X^{i+j+1} =X^{i+j}X=x^jX^{i+1}=x^{j+1}X^i$.  Thus $|X^{i+j}|=|X^i|$ for all $j\geq 0$.  So (2) holds.

Suppose (2) holds. Then since $1\in H$ we have $X^i\subseteq X^iH=X^{i+r}$ and $|X^i|=|X^{i+r}|$. Thus $X^i=X^{i+r}\in N_G(H)/H$. This proves the claim.

It now follows that the chain $|X^1|\leq |X^2|\leq \cdots$ stabilizes from $|X^{|H|}|$ and onwards and that $X^{|H|}\in N_G(H)/H$. Thus $(X^{|H|})^{[N_G(H):H]}=H$
and so $X^n=H$ as $|H|[N_G(H):H]=|N_G(H)|$ divides $n$.

Comment: I like the intent, but not the execution.  My first two quibbles are for sake of clarity: P(G) becomes a monoid (or hypergroup or whatever) when you take the appropriate generalization of the operation of G with the set P(G).  (A.k.a. I think most know of P(G) as a set and need more reminding of the operation than "google power group" to turn P(G).)  Also, it is not clear if / in NG(H)/H is quotient or set difference.  I am leaning toward the latter through type checking, but it would be better to be more explicit.  Gerhard "Ask Me About Getting Confused" Paseman, 2012.10.15

Comment: Gerhard:  the power of a semigroup is a semigroup by AB=all products ab with a in A and b in B. I meant quotient not set difference. 

Answer (score 0):

I would proove the task as follows for the case $1\in X$:

- If $X$ is a non-empty subset such that there exist an $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $m\in \mathbb{N}$ the equality $X^{m+k}=X^k$, then $X^k$ is a subgroup: as $X$ is non-empty so is $X^k$. In addition, $X^kX^k=X^k$ by our assumption. As $G$ is finite we are done.
- Why does such an $k$ exist and why is $n$ sufficient for this? In the case where $1\in X$ we have a ascending chain of subsets $X\le X^2\le ... \le X^n$. If all subsets are different $X^n$ reaches $G$ as $G$ has $n$ elements. Then we are done. Otherwise we have that the chian is stable and we are done as well.